# How to pass the user object that triggered the push notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have saved all the user's location in the installation object. And i have another object named locationObject which gets updated when the current user sends his current location.When it does, the cloud code compares his current location with all the other saved locations and send push notifications to the users who are nearby.This is my code to generate push notifications.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("locationObject", function (request) {
    var geoPoint = request.object.get("myCurrentLocation");
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.near("significantLocationUpdate", geoPoint);
    pushQuery.limit(100);

    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
            alert: "some user is nearby"
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            console.log("push was successful");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("sending push failed")// Handle error
        }
    });
});
```

Now, my question is, how can i pass along the user object that triggered the push notification along with his current location to the the users i am sending push notification to?

Comment: Have you looked into additional info in the push at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [additional data](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-customizing-your-notifications) to the push. For example:

```
data: {
  alert: "some user is nearby",
  user: [user objectId],
  latitude: [user latitude],
  longitude: [user longitude]
}
```